# perfino agent is not logging to a file even when i use the logfile directive

Tags: perfino

I do something like this
-javaagent:/usr/local/lib/perfino/perfino.jar=server=ybperfino,name=${HSTNAMESHORT}-${APPNAME},group=${YBENV}/${HSTNAMESHORT},logMBean=10,logFile=${LOG_DIR}/perfinologs/${HSTNAMESHORT}-${APPNAME}.log

basically I want the log files to be created in the log directory for the app not the home directory for the userid

but it seems like the log file isn't being created either with logfile argument or with out !

using java11 if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer - I had a competing java agent that was loading before it.
After I changed the order both java agents worked.